# When deploying updated Django code on server, the database resets

Tags: django, database, git, digital-ocean, reset

I have built an app which uses Django as a Rest API (Django rest framework). After having deployed the code on digital ocean using production grade services, everything works well. The postgresql database populates itself correctly . There is no reset of the server like on Heroku.

Except, if I change a file and push the change through gitlab(Digital ocean picks up the change and automatically deploys the updated version of the server), the database resets to its original state. I would like the server to stay as.

I have removed all migration files before pushing updates, but to no avail. I imagine it has to be something rather trivial but I can't find it.

The database is hosted also by digital ocean. I havent done any configuration. Wouldn't it be managed automatically as DO deploys the code on its servers?

Comment: Where _is_ the database? How is it configured? There's not enough information here to tell you what the problem is.

Comment: What database are you using and how is it configured? did you use any container technology to deploy your application such as Docker?

Comment: This is a postgresql 12 db

Comment: Are you storing any of your postgresql data on gitlab ?

Comment: yes there is the db.sqlite3 file on gitlab. Need to remove it?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what went wrong. Using the sqlite db while developping is one thing, but assuming when deploying your django app on a service provider that it will handle the whole db management is a 1000 steps too far.

Logically, whenever I pushed a new update to the server, the db would reset using the sqlite local db file of the project.

So I created a specific db on digital ocean, change the database config on the settings file of my django project to connect to it. Making the project use the external db. then I Just had to migrate project db structure to the external db.

And Voila. problem resolved